# SvelteKit + MariaDB (connection pools): TypeError: Cannot read private member #pool from an object whose class did not declare it

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sveltekit

I'm trying to integrate MariaDB into a SvelteKit project, and encountered an error.

What I got so far:

### Library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mariadb

### `src/lib/server/database/mariadb.ts`

```
import { DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME } from '$env/static/private';

import mariadb from 'mariadb';

const pool = mariadb.createPool({
    host: DB_HOST,
    port: Number(DB_PORT),
    user: DB_USER,
    password: DB_PASSWORD,
    database: DB_NAME,
    connectionLimit: 5,
    trace: true,
});

export const databaseConnection = pool.getConnection;
```

### `src/routes/+page.server.ts`

```
import { databaseConnection } from '$lib/server/database/mariadb';

export const load = async () => {
    const dbConnection = await databaseConnection();

    const statement = await dbConnection.prepare(
        'SELECT something FROM table WHERE condition = ?'
    );

    const result = statement.execute([1]);

    statement.close;
    
    return {
        result: result
    };
};
```

### Error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read private member #pool from an object whose class did not declare it
    at Module.getConnection node_modules/mariadb/lib/pool-promise.js:86:14)
    at load (src/routes/+page.server.ts:4:29)
    at Module.load_server_data (node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/page/load_data.js:60:41)
    at node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/page/index.js:140:19
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.